# Getting Xcode to enforce data types and constness across virtual functions

Tags: c++, xcode

So, I'm noticing that Xcode (v6.2) doesn't seem to enforce constness across pure virtual functions where as Visual Studio does. A few questions:
1) If I have a pure virtual in a base class that has a const argument and it's NOT const when defined in the derrived class... as that ANSI compliant and:
2) Is there any way to get Xcode to throw an error like Visual Studio does?

In the first block we have the header file and it has a pure virtual function.

```
// Some header file (assume include guards and all that fun stuff)
namespace Testing123
{
    class ClassA
    {
    public:
        // ************ NOTICE THAT THE ARGUMENT IS CONST!!! ***************   
        virtual double  somePureVirtualFunk( const double someNumber ) = 0;       

    protected:
        inline double getSomeFunkyNumber(){ return m_something; };
    private:
        double m_something;
    }
}
```

Now in the second file we have the header for a derived class with an inline function that defines our pure virtual from ClassA...

```
// Some header file (assume include guards and all that fun stuff)
#include "ClassA.h"

namespace Testing123
{
    class ClassB : public ClassA
    {
    public:
        // ************ NOTICE THAT THE ARGUMENT IS **NOT** CONST!!! *************   
        inline virtual double  somePureVirtualFunk( double someNumber )
        { return this->getSomeFunkyNumber(); }; 
    }
}
```

So I think that demonstrates what I'm seeing, in ClassA somePureVirtualFunk is declared as having a const argument and when it gets defined in ClassB the constness is missing. Visual Studio kindly alerts you to this fact, Xcode does not. Is there a way to get Xcode to warn me about this?

Answer (score 4):

1) It is standards compliant. Top level `const`s are ignored, so this

```
virtual double  somePureVirtualFunk( const int someNumber ) = 0;
```

is exactly the same as this

```
virtual double  somePureVirtualFunk( int someNumber ) = 0;
```

It makes no sense to set the `const` in function a *declaration*, because it is ignored. It could be used as an implementation detail used in the function's *definition*, where it would just mean the local parameter cannot be modified in the body of the function.

```
double ClassB::somePureVirtualFunk(const int someNumber )
{
  // someNumber cannot be modified here.
  // But it is local, so nobody needs to know.
}
```

Note that this only applies to top level `const`, as in your example.

2) I'm not sure how useful the warning would be, given that the function signatures are the same. A good warning would be one that tells you that you have a top-level const qualifier in a function declaration, and that it has no effect.